# Using object element to load a site and then autofill elements in it

Tags: javascript, html

In case you're wondering, the site that I am loading is our own organisations site. They want me to create an app that just displays the site and auto-fills data as needed. I'm using PhoneGap to create the app.

I have already got the website to load and display properly on the site.
I want to know how I can select elements in the loaded site and edit the data in them.

Here is how I load the site:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <object id="objectContainer" data="https://live.entry-sign.com"/>
</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can access the Elements using `HTMLObjectElement.contentDocument` but it is **readonly**, you cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var objectDocument = document.getElementById("objectContainer").contentDocument;

objectDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
// This would turn the iframe blue.
```

I'm just wondering if this will work or not.

Comment: Like sabithpocker said, it's only read only so I'm going to use the URL and pass the website info like that instead. Will need to edit the main site so it accepts the info though.